# Correct step to mount disk in debian/ubuntu system

Tags: linux

In windows, if i want to attach a new disk, I mount an empty drive, create a partition and format it. Of course it is all done in gui.

How do i accomplish the same thing in linux(debian,ubuntu) environment? i'm not even sure what keyword to look for.

Comment: You're in the wrong place. Try http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a vaguely similar GUI experience, then GParted might be what you want. You can get it by doing:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

If you want a more linuxy way, then google for fstab and fdisk.